# Firebase C++ Messaging Crashing on Startup

Tags: android, c++, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, unreal-engine4

So, I'm trying to use the Firebase c++ library in my Unreal project, but I'm getting some very consistent crashes: it crashes the first time I run it after a new uninstalling it, and works fine afterwards

Here's the stack trace I've got from firebase crash logging:

> E/art     ( 7271): No implementation found for void com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.RegistrationIntentService.nativeOnTokenReceived(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_google_firebase_messaging_cpp_RegistrationIntentService_nativeOnTokenReceived and Java_com_google_firebase_messaging_cpp_RegistrationIntentService_nativeOnTokenReceived__Ljava_lang_String_2)
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271):
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.RegistrationIntentService.nativeOnTokenReceived(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_google_firebase_messaging_cpp_RegistrationIntentService_nativeOnTokenReceived and Java_com_google_firebase_messaging_cpp_RegistrationIntentService_nativeOnTokenReceived__Ljava_lang_String_2)
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.RegistrationIntentService.nativeOnTokenReceived(Native Method)
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271):    at com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:31)
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>
> E/UncaughtException( 7271):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

It says there's no implementation for nativeOnTokenReceived, but it is implemented in the firebase c++ sdk library.
The crash happens when RegistrationIntentService is sent an intent from FcmInstanceIDListenerService, which happens when firebase gives a new token, which always happens on app startup after reinstalling it or clearing it's app data (I'm not sure if it's possible to make it happen at a different time than startup).

However, RegistrationIntentService has onHandleIntent activated, and calls nativeOnTokenReceived without any problems when my c++ listener class is initialized, during the course of the app. Does anybody know what might be causing this crash?

It might be relavent that Unreal's build process packages the static .a libraries from the sdk into a single .so before using ndk-build.

Here's the code for RegistrationIntentService and FcmInstanceIDListenerService extracted from the sdk's libmessaging_java.jar

```
FcmInstanceIDListenerService.java
    package com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp;

     import android.content.Intent;
     import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

     public class FcmInstanceIDListenerService
       extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
     {
       public void onTokenRefresh()
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
         startService(intent);
       }
     }

RegistrationIntentService.java
    package com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp;

    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

    public class RegistrationIntentService
       extends IntentService
     {
       private static final String TAG = "FirebaseRegService";

       public RegistrationIntentService()
       {
         super("FirebaseRegService");
       }

       protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
       {
         DebugLogging.log("FirebaseRegService", String.format("onHandleIntent token=%s", new Object[] {
           FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() }));
         String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
         if (token != null) {
           nativeOnTokenReceived(token);
         }
       }

       private static native void nativeOnTokenReceived(String paramString);
     }
```

Comment: Heya. Did you ever find any solution other than writing your own native function? And if not, can you share your solution here? I'm currently running into the same problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll do a little writeup once I get a chance. Expect it in a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess I'm posting my solution to this problem up here..

Firstly, I don't really know why there is a problem in the first place, but I have a feeling it has to do with Unreal's build system.
(Fun fact: I've also had unexplainable errors in Google's Protobuf libraries, when trying to use them in Unreal Engine.)

So since, the JNI couldn't find the library defined function it needed, I wrote my own function to replace it.

Basically, when you're using the Firebase Messaging C++ SDK, there's two components to include in your project: the c++ static library and headers, and a java library, `libmessaging_java.jar`
The jar file defines a few classes, most of which are good fine, but a few need to be edited, which you can do if you decompile it
(I used [this tool](http://jd.benow.ca/))

So, inside `RegistrationIntentService` I declared

```
private static native void nativeOnNewToken(String paramString);
```

and replaced the call to `nativeOnTokenReceived` with it

and in `ListenerService` I declared

```
private static native void nativeOnNewMessage(String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, Map<String, String> paramMap);
```

and added it to `writeMessageToInternalStorage()`

```
  private void writeMessageToInternalStorage(String from, String msgId, String error, Map<String, String> data)
   {
   //Added code
    nativeOnNewMessage(from, msgId, error, data);

    //I'm passing the message directly to the C++ code, rather than storing
    //it in a buffer, and processing every once in a while
    //like the sdk normally does; so surround this crap with if(false)

    if(false){
    //end added code
         try
         {
           JSONObject json = messageToJson(from, msgId, error, data);
           DebugLogging.log("FIREBASE_LISTENER", json.toString());
           writeStorageFile(json.toString());
         } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
     //added code
        }
    ///end added code
   }
```

Now, the messages and tokens are being sent to my functions, so I need to declare them:

```
#include "FirebaseMessageListener.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#include <string>
#include <map>

#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
//jni calls from the listener services
    extern "C" void Java_com_google_firebase_messaging_cpp_ListenerService_nativeOnNewMessage(JNIEnv* jenv, jobject thiz, jstring from, jstring mssgID, jstring error, jobject data) {
        UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("Entering nativeOnNewMessage *****"));
        printf("Entering nativeOnNewMessage *****");

        std::map<std::string, std::string> data_out;
        std::string messageID;
        std::string fromID;

        //code iterating through map from java, based off code from here:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/a3804cf77f0edd93f6247a055cdafb856b117eec/media/jni/android_media_MediaMetadataRetriever.cpp 
        // data is a Map<String, String>.
        if (data) {
            // Get the Map's entry Set.
            jclass mapClass = jenv->FindClass("java/util/Map");
            if (mapClass == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jmethodID entrySet =
                jenv->GetMethodID(mapClass, "entrySet", "()Ljava/util/Set;");
            if (entrySet == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jobject set = jenv->CallObjectMethod(data, entrySet);
            if (set == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            // Obtain an iterator over the Set
            jclass setClass = jenv->FindClass("java/util/Set");
            if (setClass == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jmethodID iterator =
                jenv->GetMethodID(setClass, "iterator", "()Ljava/util/Iterator;");
            if (iterator == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jobject iter = jenv->CallObjectMethod(set, iterator);
            if (iter == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            // Get the Iterator method IDs
            jclass iteratorClass = jenv->FindClass("java/util/Iterator");
            if (iteratorClass == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jmethodID hasNext = jenv->GetMethodID(iteratorClass, "hasNext", "()Z");
            if (hasNext == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jmethodID next =
                jenv->GetMethodID(iteratorClass, "next", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
            if (next == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            // Get the Entry class method IDs
            jclass entryClass = jenv->FindClass("java/util/Map$Entry");
            if (entryClass == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jmethodID getKey =
                jenv->GetMethodID(entryClass, "getKey", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
            if (getKey == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            jmethodID getValue =
                jenv->GetMethodID(entryClass, "getValue", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
            if (getValue == NULL) {
                return;
            }
            // Iterate over the entry Set
            while (jenv->CallBooleanMethod(iter, hasNext)) {
                jobject entry = jenv->CallObjectMethod(iter, next);
                jstring key = (jstring)jenv->CallObjectMethod(entry, getKey);
                jstring value = (jstring)jenv->CallObjectMethod(entry, getValue);
                const char* keyStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(key, NULL);
                if (!keyStr) {  // Out of memory
                    return;
                }
                const char* valueStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(value, NULL);
                if (!valueStr) {  // Out of memory
                    jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(key, keyStr);
                    return;
                }
                data_out.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(std::string(keyStr), std::string(valueStr)));
                jenv->DeleteLocalRef(entry);
                jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(key, keyStr);
                jenv->DeleteLocalRef(key);
                jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(value, valueStr);
                jenv->DeleteLocalRef(value);
            }
        }

        if (from != nullptr) {
            const char* valueStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(from, NULL);
            if (!valueStr) {  // Out of memory
                return;
            }
            fromID = std::string(valueStr);
            jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(from, valueStr);
        }

        if (mssgID != nullptr) {
            const char* valueStr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(mssgID, NULL);
            if (!valueStr) {  // Out of memory
                return;
            }
            messageID = std::string(valueStr);
            jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(mssgID, valueStr);
        }

        FirebaseMessageListener::Get()->onNewMessage(fromID, messageID, data_out);
    }

    extern "C" void Java_com_google_firebase_messaging_cpp_RegistrationIntentService_nativeOnNewToken(JNIEnv* jenv, jobject thiz, jstring inJNIStr) {
        UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("Entering nativeOnNewToken *****"));
        printf("Entering nativeOnNewToken *****");
        //first, put the token into a c string
        jboolean isCopy;
        const char* token = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(inJNIStr, &isCopy);
        FirebaseMessageListener::Get()->onNewToken(token);
    }

#endif
```

These pass the messages on to a singleton class I made. You can do whatever you want with them here, but I pass them along to a `firebase::messaging::Listener reference`, to try and keep compatibility with the Firebase SDK (incase I can get it working properly)

```
class RIFT411_API FirebaseMessageListener
{
private:
    static FirebaseMessageListener* self;

    //private so that new instance can only be made through call to Get()
    FirebaseMessageListener();
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
    JNIEnv * env = FAndroidApplication::GetJavaEnv();
    jobject activity = FAndroidApplication::GetGameActivityThis();
#endif

    //signals to return the key
    void getToken();

    //send the messages to the firebase sdk implemented listener, so we'll have an easier time if we ever want to move back
    firebase::messaging::Listener *listener = nullptr;

public:
    static FirebaseMessageListener* Get();

    void onNewToken(const char* token);
    void onNewMessage(std::string, std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> &data);

    void Init(firebase::messaging::Listener *listener);

    ~FirebaseMessageListener();
};
```

//

```
FirebaseMessageListener* FirebaseMessageListener::self = nullptr;


FirebaseMessageListener* FirebaseMessageListener::Get()
{
    if (self == nullptr) {
        self = new FirebaseMessageListener();
    }
    return self;
}

void FirebaseMessageListener::getToken() {
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
    //This has to happen in the main thread, or some of the FindClass() calls will fail

    UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("Trying to grab token *****"));
    printf("Trying to grab token *****");

    env = FAndroidApplication::GetJavaEnv();
    activity = FAndroidApplication::GetGameActivityThis();

    jclass cls_intent = (env)->FindClass("android/content/Intent");
    if (NULL == cls_intent) { UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Error, TEXT("Failure getting cls_intent")); return; }

    jclass cls_service = FAndroidApplication::FindJavaClass("com/google/firebase/messaging/cpp/RegistrationIntentService");
    //jclass cls_service = (env)->FindClass("com/google/firebase/messaging/cpp/RegistrationIntentService");
    if (NULL == cls_service) { UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Error, TEXT("Failure getting cls_service")); }


    // Get the Method ID of the constructor which takes an int
    jmethodID mid_Init = (env)->GetMethodID(cls_intent, "<init>", "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V");
    if (NULL == mid_Init) { UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Error, TEXT("Failure getting mid_Init")); return;}

    // Call back constructor to allocate a new instance, with an int argument
    jobject obj_intent = (env)->NewObject(cls_intent, mid_Init, activity, cls_service);
    if (NULL == obj_intent) { UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Error, TEXT("Failure getting obj_intent")); return; }

    if (NULL == activity) { UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Error, TEXT("Failure getting activity")); return; }

    jclass cls_activity = (env)->GetObjectClass(activity);
    if (NULL == cls_activity) { UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Error, TEXT("Failure getting cls_activity")); return; }

    jmethodID mid_start = (env)->GetMethodID(cls_activity, "startService", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;");
    if (NULL == mid_start) { UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Error, TEXT("Failure getting mid_start")); return; }


    UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("MADE IT TO THE END!"));
    (env)->CallObjectMethod(activity, mid_start, obj_intent);

#endif
}

void FirebaseMessageListener::onNewToken(const char* token) {
    UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("Recieving new token in Unreal! Hooray! ***** %s"), *FString(token));
    printf("Recieving new Message in Unreal! Hooray! *****\n");
    if (listener != nullptr) {
        listener->OnTokenReceived(token);
    }
}

void FirebaseMessageListener::onNewMessage(std::string from, std::string MessageID, std::map<std::string, std::string> &data) {
    UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("Recieving new Message in Unreal! Hooray! *****"));
    printf("Recieving new Message in Unreal! Hooray! *****\n");
    if (!data.empty()) {
        UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("data:"));
        typedef std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator MapIter;
        for (MapIter it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
            FString s1 = FString(it->first.c_str());
            FString s2 = FString(it->second.c_str());
            UE_LOG(FirebaseLog, Log, TEXT("  %s: %s"), *s1, *s2);
        }
    }

    ::firebase::messaging::Message message;

    message.data = data;
    message.from = from;
    message.message_id = MessageID;


    if (listener != nullptr) {
        listener->OnMessage(message);
    }
}

void FirebaseMessageListener::Init(firebase::messaging::Listener *newlistener) {
    this->listener = newlistener;
    FGraphEventRef Task = FFunctionGraphTask::CreateAndDispatchWhenReady([=]()
    {
        getToken();
    }, TStatId(), NULL, ENamedThreads::GameThread);

}

FirebaseMessageListener::FirebaseMessageListener()
{
    self = this;
}

FirebaseMessageListener::~FirebaseMessageListener()
{
}
```

One thing about this is that you won't get data from notifications that are recieved while your app is closed. That data is packaged in an Intent, and I've almost got a good way to get it, to I'll probably post that once I finish it

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I checked the `messaging.a` and it doesn't seem to contain a defintion for `Java_com_..._nativeOnTokenReceived`, so I just implemented that myself, which seems to work. My feeling is a problem in Firebase's C++ SDK, actually. Problem is that I receive this way too early, before anything from Unreal has loaded. I guess that's also why you have the `CreateAndDispatchWhenReady` / `getToken` part?

Comment: It was a while ago that I did this, so I don't remember all of my reasoning. I'm pretty sure that the `CreateAndDispatchWhenReady` was intended to ensure that `getToken()` was run on the game thread, although it it would also delay it until Unreal's windup was done, which may have been what made it work

Seems really weird that `messaging.a` doesn't have a definition for `...OnTokenRecieved()` though. It has to be defined somewhere

Comment: I was wondering about it too, but in the end it allowed my definition without complaints and that works fine. What I also do now is add a small `startService(new Intent(RegistrationIntentService.class))` function to the GameActivity (through UPL, since I have Firebase as a plugin), and then trigger that function through one simple JNI call when the actual game requests the token.

Comment: So, I've finally gotten back to working on this. First thing I did was update to the newest version of the c++ sdk, and it seems to work without modification

Answer (score 0):

com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp just listens for messages sent by FCM's service and forwards them to the Android C++ library (libmessaging.a).  It looks like the problem is due to the firebase-messaging aar not being included in your application which had led to the com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp package not being loaded as it depends upon classes in the firebase-messaging aar that are not present.

For example, when building using gradle it's possible to include the aar using the following https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/blob/master/messaging/testapp/build.gradle#L93

Right now it's a little tricky to include aars in Unreal projects as described in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/eGNr36dpB70/VXVqBfL1BAAJ .  Basically you'll need to unzip (aars are just zip files) the firebase-messaging aar (look under ${ANDROID_HOME}/extras/google/firebase/firebase-messaging) and it's dependencies (you'll need to read each *.pom file to get the dependencies) and include the various .jars, AndroidManifest.xml files and resources extracted from each aar in your Unreal project.  It's very important to make sure each AndroidManifest.xml gets merged into your final application's AndroidManifest.xml so that all services and content providers used by Firebase are included.

Comment: Hi there, I appreciate an answer to such an old question!

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the question, but I "inserted" gradle into the tail end of my build of Unreal's build process to take care of the AAR downloading and merging, so I all of them, and they worked recieving messages


It was crashing when it tried to send that message to the c code, by calling a native function in the static library included in the ndk sdk. (but only when it called that initial function)


I never managed to figure out why that fcn crashed it, but I did workaround it by writing my own function in my project code that recieved the message.

Comment: You're answer has a lot of info it took me a while to find, so I hope it helps someone :)